# Faster way to get Named Range of Excel Cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large range of cells (over 600) each with a Name assigned. The entire worksheet has close to 3,000 named ranges. I'm bulding an array of these so I can evaluate each on a set of rules to be copied into a summary sheet. The rest of the code is fast enough but this part is much slower.

My code to get the names is essentially:

```
s = Timer
Debug.Print x & ": " & Timer - s & " seconds": x = x + 1
For intIndex = 1 To rngQuestions.Rows.Count
    astrNames(intIndex - 1, 0) = rngQuestions.Cells(intIndex, 1).Name.Name ' THIS IS SLOW
    astrNames(intIndex - 1, 1) = rngQuestions.Cells(intIndex, 1).Address
Next
Debug.Print x & ": " & Timer - s & " seconds": x = x + 1
```

This is taking over 1.5 seconds. I've tested commenting the slow line out. This part then only takes 0.2.

Is there another way to get the Name of a large range like this?

I've tested building a separate Dictionary or Array of names and calling that in my loop however the Dictionary gave no improvement and Array was actually sometimes slower. Here's a sample of the code used for those methods: https://gist.github.com/snoopen/e6fd0d72a88b2179cf7a

Comment: `rngQuestions.Name.Name` is being evaluated over and over again: it will always return the same value, so just do it once.

Comment: Yep sorry, I simplified my code and forgot to leave the Cell() bit in. Question updated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using

```
Range("A1").ListNames
```

Or

```
for each n in thisworkbook.names
    debug.print n.name & " - " & n.RefersTo
next n
```

Comment: I've updated my question to mention I have 3,000 named ranges in total and I'm only interested in the 600 in my range. I've tried a modification of your second suggestion where I build then search an array or dictionary with the names but it ends up taking just as long.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve on that performance by writing your own optimised lookup.  I created a crude method and got better than a x100 performance.

General method:

- Load a list of all named ranges and address into memory (I used an array).  Do this once at the start of your code
- Write an optimised search function to find a specified address in the data (array)
- In your main loop build the address and use your search function to get the Name

The search function I tried was quite crude: a simple sequential search, but starting at the index where the last name was found.  If the names are roughly sorted this can be quite optimal.  YMMV especially if your names are not patterned (in which case a binary search would be better)

I include my test code for reference.  It will need work to become production code

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub z()
    Range("H1").ListNames
End Sub


Sub Demo()
    Dim t1 As Long, t2 As Long
    Dim vAddr As Variant, vName As Variant
    Dim addr As String, Nm As String
    Dim n As Long

    ' Names stored on sheet for conveniance
    ' These lists created with .ListNames
    vAddr = Range("I1:I3172").Value2 ' Names stored here
    vName = Range("H1:H3172").Value2 ' Address stored here

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    t1 = GetTickCount
    For j = 1 To 10  ' loop for test purposes
    For i = 5 To 605 ' find 600 names
        addr = "=Sheet1!$C$" & i
        n = FindAddr(vAddr, addr)
        Nm = vName(n, 1)
    Next
    Next
    t2 = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print t2 - t1


    t1 = GetTickCount
    For j = 1 To 10
    For i = 5 To 605
        Nm = Cells(i, 3).Name.Name
    Next
    Next
    t2 = GetTickCount
    Debug.Print t2 - t1
End Sub

Function FindAddr(dat As Variant, item As String) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim fnd As Boolean
    Static init As Long

    If init = 0 Then init = 1
    For i = init To UBound(dat, 1)
        If dat(i, 1) = item Then
            fnd = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not fnd Then
    For i = 1 To init - 1
        If dat(i, 1) = item Then
            fnd = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    End If
    init = i
    FindAddr = i
End Function
```

On my hardware results were 109 ms vs 23,805 ms (that's for 50 x 600 lookups)